# Smooth following of user's location in MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, mkmapview

I would like to follow user's blue dot same way Google Maps do it. It means when the location is changing then the map (or it's center) should smoothly follow it. But when I use standard way with delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    [map setCenterCoordinate:map.userLocation.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

or keyvalue observer on `mapview.userLocation` then move of the map is quite "choppy", it quickly "jumps" to new location even if I use `animated` parameter.

In addition I think that the blue dot itself doesn't move so smoothly as in native Google Maps app and often jumps to new location instead of moving there.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: iOS 5 adds this feature with tracking mode. Finally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'hi Jak

I've tried to solve this as well but it looks like MKMapView might be using some fancy stuff between updates to predict the next position and make the movement smoother.

If you look at the way they handle the compass they are doing a lot of filtering as the raw compass data is not terribly steady so they make it really slick and smooth.

Also, notice when tracking you can zoom but not pan. I've failed to replicate this functionality in my app even with scrolling turned off, it still scrolls when you are zooming if you pan your fingers around.

I guess they don't expose everything just to keep ahead of us :)
D

Comment: Well, I came to the same conclusion. ;o) Maps app has to use some private methods we can't. I also tried to put `setCenterCoordinate:animated:` to an UIView animation but with no effect.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `CLLocationManager` delegate update methods to get the current location about every second, saved the previous location and interpolated between those. It's a little more effort, but t makes the tracking a lot smoother. Here is my code:

```
#define zoomSpan MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001f, 0.001f)

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocation *lastLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

...

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = locations[locations.count - 1];
    // Set to last location, for faster setting to correct position
    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.lastLocation.coordinate, zoomSpan) animated:NO];

    // Locations in-between coordinates for smooth tracking
    CLLocationDegrees deltaLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude - self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees deltaLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude - self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    NSArray *locationsArray = @[[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude + deltaLat * 0.2)
                                                           longitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude + deltaLon * 0.2)],
                                [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude + deltaLat * 0.4)
                                                           longitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude + deltaLon * 0.4)],
                                [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude + deltaLat * 0.6)
                                                           longitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude + deltaLon * 0.6)],
                                [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude + deltaLat * 0.8)
                                                           longitude:(self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude + deltaLon * 0.8)],
                                currentLocation];

    float timer = 0;
    for (CLLocation *nextLocation in locationsArray) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateMapCenterLocation:) withObject:nextLocation afterDelay:timer];
        timer += 0.2;
    }
    self.lastLocation = currentLocation;
}

- (void)updateMapCenterLocation:(CLLocation *)location
{
    [self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(location.coordinate, zoomSpan) animated:YES];
}
```

Make sure that the class you are using this in (normally the view controller that holds the map view) is set to the `CLLocationManager`'s delegate and implementing the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol.

Some additional comments:

- The behavior of this code is similar to `MKUserTracking`, but this doesn't support custom set zoom levels. There seems to be a bug resetting the zoom level when starting tracking, therefore this workaround.
- `zoomSpan` is currently fixed, but you also can use the span of the current region with `self.mapView.region.span`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
- (void)adjustRegion:(CLLocation*)location {
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 150.0, 150.0);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Oh, that's a singleton class where I saved some params. Just copied and pasted that line. Sry, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @Lego doesn't that force the user to use the zoom level you've defined?  (Rather than let them custom define it)

Comment: @RonLugge Well, of course you can set the zoom level dynamically by listening to the specific delegate method, mmmmmmh I think it was ´mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:´.